# Is it possible to set a class object as a string value in C#

Tags: c#, wifi, simplewifi

I'm using the simpleWifi library to implement connections to Wi-Fi access points and I'm trying to set a string value to a class object. Down below in my example, I'm trying to set the variable WifiPoint to a string value from another window form.

```
AccessPoint WifiPoint = frmSettings.wifi_selected_name.ToString();
```

**SimpleWiFi class**

```
namespace SimpleWifi
{
    public class AccessPoint
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public uint SignalStrength { get; }
        public bool HasProfile { get; }
        public bool IsSecure { get; }
        public bool IsConnected { get; }

        public bool Connect(AuthRequest request, bool overwriteProfile = false);
        public void ConnectAsync(AuthRequest request, bool overwriteProfile = false, Action<bool> onConnectComplete = null);
        public void DeleteProfile();
        public string GetProfileXML();
        public bool IsValidPassword(string password);
        public sealed override string ToString();
    }
}
```

My attempt to do due this has resulted in the error showing "Cannot convert type 'string' to 'SimpleWifi.AccessPoint'

Comment: You have set the type of WifiPoint to AccessPoint which is a class and you are trying to set a string value for a class type variable. It will always fail.

Comment: No, its wrong, you can't assign a string value to class object . Why can't you save it in "Name" like this  
AccessPoint wifiPoint =new AccessPoint(); 
wifiPoint.Name= frmSettings.wifi_selected_name.ToString();

Comment: you can override the ```ToString()``` method and Implement it yourself By your own way

Comment: I tried using the ToString() method but it still failed

Comment: Also when I tried creating a new object as Noorul described it didn't work either saying that the constructor doesn't take 0 arguments

Comment: Then you have posted incomplete code here. Please post all the code if you are having any parameterized constructors in the AccessPoint class post them here

Comment: That's all the code I have because I installed the simpleWiFi library via the package manager command prompt

Comment: Does this Access point class belong to the same library?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it belongs to the same library

Comment: You need to insspect using intellisense what needs to be passed to its constructor to create an object of the AccessPoint class var obj = new AccessPoint(Inspect what params it needs); then assign the resultant obj.Name = frmSettings.wifi_selected_name.ToString();

Comment: There are only "get"  is available in those properties, you can't "set" anything. Thats why you were not able to assign any value to "Name".

Comment: That probably explains why, I can't modify the file because it's in the metadata

Comment: yeah, that may be with purpose. If so you can only get the values from the lib, could not set .

Comment: It would be possible with **implicit operator** but not the way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look on the intent of the library.

The constructor code is

```
internal AccessPoint(WlanInterface interfac, 
              WlanAvailableNetwork network)
    {
        _interface = interfac;
        _network = network;
    }
```

The intent of the author is for library consumers, to never create an instance of AccessPoint directly.

In the main example, he does the following to create then

```
    IEnumerable<AccessPoint> accessPoints = wifi.GetAccessPoints().OrderByDescending(ap => ap.SignalStrength);

        int i = 0;
        foreach (AccessPoint ap in accessPoints)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1} {2}% Connected: {3}", i++, ap.Name, ap.SignalStrength, ap.IsConnected);

        return accessPoints;
```

So,  as he does, find available wifi networks, get the access points and check from your config values, if they are the target ones

Comment: Hey thanks for explaining but in my application it's not a console project. I'm still trying to find a way to work around setting the AccessPoint as a string value. I've tried using AccessPoint WiFiPoint = (AccessPoint)cbWifiname.Tag but still no luck.

Comment: @SahilBora what Athanasios told you is correct, all you need to do is find the access point object from the list of access points where the access point name equals the string you have. Using Linq: `AccessPoint accessPoint = accessPoints.First(ap => ap.Name == frmSettings.wifi_selected_name.ToString())`.